# How to properly import media on Banshee?

Tags: music, banshee

I'd like to ask you about Banshee. I have imported media from my Windows partition, renamed it and so on, but after restarting my laptop and running Banshee again I can't play my track because "File not found". What's more: I do import media all over again, it "visually" doesn't change anything (still the same number of tracks), but all of a sudden it starts working. Is there a way to fix it? I gotta say that importing media every time is quiet annoying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the Windows drive before starting `Banshee` and all your media will show, you can do this by opening the drive in the your files application first or use `Disks` to set it to auto mount at boot.

Open `Disks` from the `Dash` (top left) and choose your drive on the left. Now click the little three cogs icon under the partition information [image], and choose `Edit Mount Options`.

Turn off `Automatic Mount options` and check `Mount at Startup`

[image]

Now when you boot the drive will be mounted automatically and all your content will show in `Banshee`.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a new Linux user, so I absolutely forgot about mounting partition manually.